# Change return of function in c

Tags: c, return, boolean, xor

so I have a function1 which either returns 0 or 1.

I have a function2 which receives function1 as argument. Now, in some cases i want to use function1 inside function2 normally, so i just call `function2(function1);`

In other cases, I want to use function1 inside function 2, but I want function2 to receive 1 from function1 when it returns 0 and receive 0 from function1 when it returns 1.

In other words, if function 1 returns 0, function2 gets 1. If function 1 returns 1, function2 gets 0.

I tried to call using a XOR(`function2(function1 ^1);`) but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

PS: I know this may sound confusing, and I apologize for that.

EDIT:
Sorry everyone, forgot to mention function2 receives pointer to a function, and not just the result of function1.

Comment: you can write it in function2: 
int ret = 1-function1(); If function1() returns 1, ret will be 1-1=0. If function1 returns 0, ret will be 1-0=1.

Comment: make sure you're using parentheses to actually call  function1: `function1()`.  Your xor should work as long as function1 returns 0 or 1. You also could use `!` (logical not).

Comment: What do you mean by *that doesn't seem to work*? What error message? Does it compile, or just not produce correct results? And `function2(function1)` is invalid C syntax for calling `function1`.

Comment: Actually.... `function2(function1)` will compile in `gcc` and warn you that you're casting from a pointer to integer without a cast.

Comment: Your function2 receives a pointer to a function as a parameter or you just the result of calling function1?

Comment: @cenouro my function2 receives pointer to a function.

Comment: Sorry everyone, forgot to mention function2 receives pointer to a function, and not just the result of function1.

Comment: Then @dbush solution is the most appropriate one. What you can do to make it more elegant is change your function2 so that it can receive an arbitrary number of parameters. That way, you can just pass function1 if you wanna it to behave normally or pass a second parameter to trigger the `not`.

Comment: Create a wrapper function that negates the result. Pass the wrapper as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to pass a parameter to `function2` to tell it how to interpret the return value of `function1`.

Assuming your functions are defined as follows:

```
int function1(void);
void function2(int (*func)(void), int normalReturn);
```

Then inside of `function2`, you can do this:

```
int result;
if (normalReturn) {
    result = func();
} else {
    result = !func();
}
```

You can then call `function2` like for normal use:

```
function2(function1, 0);
```

And like this for inverted use:

```
function2(function1, 1);
```

Comment: Or `function2(int (*func)(void), ...)`.

Comment: Thank you, although I thought I didn't need to change function2, just the way I called it, this worked!

Comment: @RuiLoureiro Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

As Karoly Horvath mentioned in the comments, you can create a "wrapper" function that calls `function1` and reverses its return value. This avoids the need to modify `function2`:

```
int function1_neg(void)
{
    return function1() ^ 1;
}

...

function2(function1_neg);
```